# Bulk send draft messages from Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird

We imported hundreds of emails ready to send into the drafts folder of Thunderbird. Rather than click everyone individually, how can we bulk send? In Outlook there's a macro to do so - not sure if Thunderbird has something else. I wasn't able to find an addon either.

Comment: One option might be to import them directly into 'Unsent Messages' directory (or move them from `Drafts` file in `$THUNDERBIRD_PROFILE_DIR/Mail/Local Folders/` into `./Unsent Messages` file), changing `X-Mozilla-Status` header to `0800` - then you can simply relaunch T-Bird, right-click 'Outbox' and choose 'Send Unsent Messages'